# Hilbert Series of $k[x_1, ... x_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, hilbert-polynomial

For the algebra $A = k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ graded by degree.  How does one find the Hilbert series.  For a single variable, the hilbert series is simply 
$1+t+t^2+\dots = 1/(1-t)$.

Comment: Can you explain [what it means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_series_and_Hilbert_polynomial#Definitions_and_main_properties) when say $n=2$ ?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is $(1 + t + t^2 + \dots)^n = \frac{1}{(1-t)^n}$.

Because you can easily see that adding a variable will multiply the Hilbert serie by $1 + t + t^2 + t^3 + \dots $.

Answer (score 1):

You want to count the number of monomials of degree $n$ obtainable from $x_1,\ldots,x_k$. This is exactly a multiset on $[k]$ with $n$ elements, and there are $$\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$ of those. On the other hand, this number is equal to 
$$(-1)^n \binom{-n}{k}$$ which is the coefficient of $t^n$ in $(1-t)^{-n}$, whence the Hilbert series of your ring is this rational function of $t$.